# Facebook status updates from my own fan page

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-fql

I am trying to retrieve my own facebook posts to show on my website.
Looking at SDK documentation I couldn't find it anywhere, neither with the FQL queries.
I could only find how to get the logged user statuses.

Is there a way to do what i need?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be authenticated to get access to the `feed` API object or `stream` FQL table. Both return your Facebook posts.

The easiest is to create an app, and use your app id to authenticate, then make this API call:

```
$result = $facebook->api('/USER_ID_OR_USERNAME/feed', 'GET');
```

You'll be limited to public updates. If you want more detailed updates, you will need to authenticate the person whose stream you wish to get, obtain a long-term access token and store this in your database.